# Python sparse matrix multiplication

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I would like to ask what are some options how to make multiplication of two sparse matrices more efficient and faster?

Currently I am using python package scipy `.dot` method running on CPU. The shape of my matrices are around (500 000 x 500 000). Both are sparse, we can claim sparsity is around 20%.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] illustrating what you are asking about.

Comment: I think 20% is too high to see much advantage to using `scipy.sparse`.  Still with that shape you might still need it.  I've seen past posts about using a MKL library to accelerate sparse calculations.  (The scipy sparse multiplication is partly written in python/cython, but can make use of external libraries for key parts.)

Comment: Imho there is no magic flag there. Switch the (easy to use) library and try (much harder to use) alternatives (Intel's MKL, suitesparse, ...). But in general: `20%` sounds quite non-sparse and sparse-matmul is very complex. This is not much about raw arithmetic-calculation power (i'm mentioning this because of your mentioning of CPU), but a lot about memory-allocation strategies (while guessing where non-zeros appear).

Comment: A 500k x 500k matrix at 20% sparsity is about 800gb in memory. Two of them, plus allocating the output array, means around 2.5TB. At this scale you should consider changing whatever has brought you to this point.

Comment: That said mkl will multi thread sparse ops (scipy doesn't) and there's a wrapper for it, so I'd try that if you can get your array sizes down a bit.

Comment: Thank you for guidance. I will have a look at the Intel's MKL library for sure. Is in this sparse matrix multiplication problem also possibility to utilise somehow running it on GPU? As I understand it GPU is better for matrix or vector operations, but when they are represented in the dense form. (Which would be really hard for me in terms of memory).

Comment: Moving a large matrix multiplication into gpu is usually only worth it if you're using the product in gpu for something else. Otherwise the math performance is outweighed by the memory copy.